# Basic info on how to export BLOB as files

Tags: sql, firebird

I have researched on how to export BLOBs to image.  A DB has an `IMAGE` column storing several thousand images.  I thought of exporting the table but I get a `BLOB` file error in *EMS SQL Manager* for InterBase and Firebird.

There have been good posts, but I have still not been able to succeed.

1. [SQL scripts to insert File to BLOB field and export BLOB to File](http://makdns.blogspot.mx/2012/02/sql-server-blob-import-and-export.html)

   This example has appeared on numerous pages, including Microsoft's site.  I am using INTERBASE (Firebird). I have not found anything related to enabling xp_shell for Firebird, or *EMS SQL Manager* for InterBase and Firebird (which I have also installed).  My guess is: its not possible.  I also tried Installing SQL Server Express, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2012.  I am at a dead end without having even connected to the server.  The reason being I have not managed to start the server.  Followed the guide at technet.microsoft: [How to: Start SQL Server Agent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191454%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but there are no services on the right pane to me.
2. PHP file to download entire column (may not post link due to rep limitation).

   It has a MySQL connect section that daunts me.  There on my computer is the DB as a `GDB` file, I also have XAMPP.  I can figure out a way to use this as a localhost environment.  I hope this is making sense.
3. Last solution is to use `bcp`, an idea posted on Stack Overflow titled: fastest way to export blobs from table into individual files.  I read the documentation, installed it, but cannot connect to server. I use `-S PC-PC -U xxx -P xxx` (The server must be wrong)  But the information I find all uses `-T` (Windows Authentication)

Summing up. I am using Firebird, as *EMS SQL Manager*.  I try to extract all images from images table into individual files.  These tools both have SQL script screens, but it appears to be in conjunction with xp shell.  What would you suggest? Am I using the wrong SQL manager to accomplish this?

Comment: `xp_shell`, `bcp` and "SQL Server Management Studio" are tools that are only available with Microsoft SQL Server. They will not work with any other database. "Microsoft SQL Server" is a different DBMS product and will not enable you to export data from a Firebird DBMS. Installing it is a waste of time. How exactly do you want those images exported? What do you want to do once they are extracted? Exporting data is essentially a job for a SQL client tool. Did you try other tools (that are intended for Firebird) except EMS SQL Manager?

Comment: No, I haven't found / tried another tool. My goal is to add them to another DB. But by hyperlinks. Stored in a separate directory of their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Use isql command [`BLOBDUMP`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-command-blobdump) to write a blob to file,
- Use a client library (eg Jaybird for Java, Firebird .net provider for C#) to retrieve the data,
- With PHP you can use [`ibase_blob_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-get.php) in a loop to get bytes from the blob, and write those to a file.

I don't use nor know EMS SQL Manager, so I don't know if (and how) you can export a blob with that.

The example you link to, and almost all tools you mention are for Microsoft SQL Server, not for Firebird; so it is no wonder those don't work.

### Example in Java

A basic example to save blobs to disk using Java 8 (might also work on Java 7) would be:

```java
/**
 * Example to save images to disk from a Firebird database.
 * <p>
 * Code assumes a table with the following structure:
 * <pre>
 * CREATE TABLE imagestorage (
 *     filename VARCHAR(255),
 *     filedata BLOB SUB_TYPE BINARY
 * );
 * </pre>
 * </p>
 */
public class StoreImages {
    // Replace testdatabase with alias or path of database
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/testdatabase?charSet=utf-8";
    private static final String USER = "sysdba";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "masterkey";
    private static final String DEFAULT_FOLDER = "D:\\Temp\\target";

    private final Path targetFolder;

    public StoreImages(String targetFolder) {
        this.targetFolder = Paths.get(targetFolder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        final String targetFolder = args.length == 0 ? DEFAULT_FOLDER : args[0];
        final StoreImages storeImages = new StoreImages(targetFolder);
        storeImages.store();
    }

    private void store() throws IOException, SQLException {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(targetFolder)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(String.format("The folder %s does not exist", targetFolder));
        }
        try (
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT filename, filedata FROM imagestorage")
        ) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                final Path targetFile = targetFolder.resolve(rs.getString("FILENAME"));
                if (Files.exists(targetFile)) {
                    System.out.printf("File %s already exists%n", targetFile);
                    continue;
                }
                try (InputStream data = rs.getBinaryStream("FILEDATA")) {
                    Files.copy(data, targetFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Example in C#

Below is an example in C#, it is similar to the code above.

```cs
class StoreImages
{
    private const string DEFAULT_FOLDER = @"D:\Temp\target";
    private const string DATABASE = @"D:\Data\db\fb3\fb3testdatabase.fdb";
    private const string USER = "sysdba";
    private const string PASSWORD = "masterkey";

    private readonly string targetFolder;
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public StoreImages(string targetFolder)
    {
        this.targetFolder = targetFolder;
        connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Database = DATABASE,
            UserID = USER,
            Password = PASSWORD
        }.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string targetFolder = args.Length == 0 ? DEFAULT_FOLDER : args[0];
        var storeImages = new StoreImages(targetFolder);
        storeImages.store();
    }

    private void store()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetFolder))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The folder {0} does not exist", targetFolder), targetFolder);
        }
        using (var connection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new FbCommand("SELECT filename, filedata FROM imagestorage", connection))
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string targetFile = Path.Combine(targetFolder, reader["FILENAME"].ToString());
                    if (File.Exists(targetFile))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File {0} already exists", targetFile);
                        continue;
                    }

                    using (var fs = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        byte[] filedata = (byte[]) reader["FILEDATA"];
                        fs.Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link where BLOBDUMP is discussed? I figured there could be a way to export the data as SQL, import to Microsoft DBMS and use one of the links shared

Comment: I will go head and mark this as answered.  The Isql command for firebird is my priority right now.  Any idea though, how to make it into a loop to write every single BLOB to its separate jpeg?.

Comment: Would you know how to produce the Bolb Id, I am at a loss where it explains:   
SQL> select proj_id, proj_desc
CON> from project
CON> where proj_id = 'MKTPR';

I dont know what any of that means. ( MKTPR, proj_id, proj_dec)

Comment: @juliositges it is an example query against the example employee database included with Firebird. You need to substitute your own query for the Blob you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I succeded in exporting a BLOB into its jpg.  There are thousands of images stored.  In order to export them all, correct me if I´m wrong, the contents of column "image_id" need to be read, then; every id needs to parsed one at a time in order to get the blob ID.  Which is turned over to a exporting command.  But I cannot write hello world without help in C++, or C#.  Where would you start?

Comment: @JulioSitges In the weekend I will see if I can write a simple example in Java and/or C#.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  Today I tried your C# code, but I need a bit more help.  I am usinf VS2013 and I dont know which project type to start.  Or what namespace to include.  I did dome googling and found that others where using `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` so, I am at a point where I´m trying to add a reference to my project.  Basically I am asking to please bear with me as i am in need of more context.  I appreciate your help. =)

Comment: @JulioSitges As a project type use a C# Console Application (if you want to replicate my testcode), as to the dependency: use NuGet to add Firebird ADO.NET Data provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient).

Comment: will do and report back.  the whole depebdency I will need to google.  but does sound straightforward.  It should resolve without issue.

Comment: @JulioSitges You probably triggered an exception and it wants to have that file for debugging. You should be able to ignore it. Just look at the exception you receive. However, consider posting to the firebird-net-provider mailinglist instead (or ask a new question).

Comment: I ran your code.  I get a blank console window.   AND ALL MY IMAGES IN A FOLDER!!

Comment: @JulioSitges Watch out for case sensitivity of columnnames, maybe it is actually `IMAGE_ID`, not `image_ID`. But as I said, otherwise post a new question with all the details.

Comment: YOU ROCK! 
THANKS A MIILLION.

Comment: I apologize for all the nuissance! IT ACTUALLY WORKED LIKE A CHARM.