# How can I export the images from my database?

Tags: blob, firebird, ibexpert

I have to export images (blob) from my database (Firebird) using IBExpert, how can I do it?

Comment: I'd just fire-up LinqPad and use `OleDbConnection`.

Comment: I have removed your off-topic request for suggestions for alternative tools.

Comment: I don't use IBExpert myself, but the [documentation](https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.DefinitionBlob) suggests you can export through the IBExpert [Blob Viewer/Editor](https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.BlobViewer-Editor)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [ISQL's blobdump](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-command-blobdump).

Comment: IBExpert comes with IBScript engine, i don't know if it includes commands for Windows File I/O

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Basic info on how to export BLOB as files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212166/basic-info-on-how-to-export-blob-as-files)